# SWT/JFace TextCellEditor Field Assist Not Working

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am trying to execute a code block extending the TextCellEditor and using org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist  to fire the content proposal. Code is executing fine but the content proposal pop up is not being fired. Also the cell is not editable. Please let me know what is wrong here?

```
public class Snippet060TextCellEditorWithContentProposal {
private static class Color {
    public String name;

    public Color(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public static class TextCellEditorWithContentProposal extends
        TextCellEditor {

    private ContentProposalAdapter contentProposalAdapter;
    private boolean popupOpen = false; // true, iff popup is currently open

    public TextCellEditorWithContentProposal(Composite parent,
            IContentProposalProvider contentProposalProvider,
            KeyStroke keyStroke, char[] autoActivationCharacters) {
        super(parent);

        enableContentProposal(contentProposalProvider, keyStroke,
                autoActivationCharacters);
    }

    private void enableContentProposal(
            IContentProposalProvider contentProposalProvider,
            KeyStroke keyStroke, char[] autoActivationCharacters) {
        contentProposalAdapter = new ContentProposalAdapter(text,
                new TextContentAdapter(), contentProposalProvider,
                keyStroke, autoActivationCharacters);

        // Listen for popup open/close events to be able to handle focus
        // events correctly
        contentProposalAdapter
                .addContentProposalListener(new IContentProposalListener2() {

                    public void proposalPopupClosed(
                            ContentProposalAdapter adapter) {
                        popupOpen = false;
                    }

                    public void proposalPopupOpened(
                            ContentProposalAdapter adapter) {
                        popupOpen = true;
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Return the {@link ContentProposalAdapter} of this cell editor.
     * 
     * @return the {@link ContentProposalAdapter}
     */
    public ContentProposalAdapter getContentProposalAdapter() {
        return contentProposalAdapter;
    }

    protected void focusLost() {
        if (!popupOpen) {
            // Focus lost deactivates the cell editor.
            // This must not happen if focus lost was caused by activating
            // the completion proposal popup.
            super.focusLost();
        }
    }

    protected boolean dependsOnExternalFocusListener() {
        // Always return false;
        // Otherwise, the ColumnViewerEditor will install an additional
        // focus listener
        // that cancels cell editing on focus lost, even if focus gets lost
        // due to
        // activation of the completion proposal popup. See also bug 58777.
        return false;
    }
}

private static class ColorNameEditingSupport extends EditingSupport {
    private TextCellEditorWithContentProposal cellEditor;

    public ColorNameEditingSupport(TableViewer viewer) {
        super(viewer);

        IContentProposalProvider contentProposalProvider = new SimpleContentProposalProvider(
                new String[] { "red", "green", "blue" });
        cellEditor = new TextCellEditorWithContentProposal(
                viewer.getTable(), contentProposalProvider, null, null);
    }

    protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
        return (element instanceof Color);
    }

    protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
        return cellEditor;
    }

    protected Object getValue(Object element) {
        return ((Color) element).name;
    }

    protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {
        ((Color) element).name = value.toString();
        getViewer().update(element, null);
    }

}

public Snippet060TextCellEditorWithContentProposal(Shell shell) {
    final TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.BORDER
            | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    final Table table = viewer.getTable();
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    final TableViewerColumn colorColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer,
            SWT.LEFT);
    colorColumn.getColumn().setText("Color name");
    colorColumn.getColumn().setWidth(200);
    colorColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider());
    colorColumn.setEditingSupport(new ColorNameEditingSupport(viewer));

    viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());

    ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy activationSupport = new ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy(
            viewer) {
        protected boolean isEditorActivationEvent(
                ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent event) {
            return event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.TRAVERSAL
                    || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.MOUSE_DOUBLE_CLICK_SELECTION
                    || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.PROGRAMMATIC
                    || (event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.KEY_PRESSED && event.keyCode == KeyLookupFactory
                            .getDefault().formalKeyLookup(
                                    IKeyLookup.ENTER_NAME));
        }
    };
    activationSupport.setEnableEditorActivationWithKeyboard(true);

    /*
     * Without focus highlighter, keyboard events will not be delivered to
     * ColumnViewerEditorActivationStragety#isEditorActivationEvent(...)
     * (see above)
     */
    FocusCellHighlighter focusCellHighlighter = new FocusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter(
            viewer);
    TableViewerFocusCellManager focusCellManager = new TableViewerFocusCellManager(
            viewer, focusCellHighlighter);

    TableViewerEditor.create(viewer, focusCellManager, activationSupport,
            ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_VERTICAL
                    | ColumnViewerEditor.KEYBOARD_ACTIVATION);

    viewer.setInput(createModel());
}

private Color[] createModel() {
    return new Color[] { new Color("red"), new Color("green") };
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();

    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    new Snippet060TextCellEditorWithContentProposal(shell);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }

    display.dispose();
}
 }
```

Comment: We can't tell you much until you show us the code.

Comment: Yes sure ..Actually I was editing ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as expected, did'nt realize that cells are registered for mouse double click action. Double click brings up the pop up